# ASP.NET Page / MasterPage life cycle

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, lifecycle, page-lifecycle

Trying to understand how after `MasterPage` render, the content of `Page` already exists in HtmlTextOutput?

ASP.NET, first calling Page.Render, then Page renders it's children controls and MasterPage is in theory "child control" of page. If so, how then after MasterPage.Render completes it contains the output for all other child controls of Page? How Master.Render, "calls" render of page itself and it's child controls?

Example:
MasterPage:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MAIN.master.cs" Inherits="Demo.MAIN" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        ContentPlaceHolder - BEFORE
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        ContentPlaceHolder - AFTER
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
public partial class MAIN : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        base.Render(writer);
        //At this point HtmlTextWriter already contains the output of all page child controls...how it's happen?
    }
```

Page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MAIN.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MAIN_PAGE.aspx.cs" Inherits="Demo.MAIN_PAGE" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
CONTENT
<TL:MyButton id="ServerControl" Text="btn" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
public partial class MAIN_PAGE : MyPage
{
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        base.Render(writer);
    }
}
```